# RoR: Carrierwave file upload - can't convert nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, upload, carrierwave

I have tried to implement the multiple file upload as suggested in the [carrierwave gem](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) readme.

The line that gives the error 'can't convert nil into String' is

```
@event = Event.new(event_params)
```

from my create action. `event_params` is defined by

```
params.require(:event).permit(:name, :description, ... lots of params ..., {images: []})
```

In the form view the file field is given by

```
<%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true %>
```

When I delete this line it gets rid of the error, but obviously doesn't upload the files. The error occurs even when I select several files in this field. Does anyone know what's going wrong?

```
app/models/event.rb

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :swipes
  has_many :event_images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_images
  mount_uploader :headerImage, HeaderImageUploader
  mount_uploader :images, ImagesUploader
  geocoded_by :full_street_address
  after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?
  after_validation :reverse_geocode, :if => :latitude_changed?
  # Event validations
  validates :name, :presence => true, length: { in: 5..30 }           
  validates :title, :presence => true, length: { in: 5..60 }
  validates :description, :presence => true, length: { in: 5..2500 }
  validates :headerImage, :presence => true
  validates :venue, :presence => true
  validates :street_address, :presence => true
  validates :post_code, :presence => true
  validate :check_begin_time
  validates :price, :presence => true
  validates :host_name, :presence => true

  def check_begin_time
    if door_time.blank? and start_time.blank?
        errors.add(:base, 'At least one of "door time" and "start time" must be filled in')
     #one at least must be filled in, add a custom error message
     return false
    else
     return true
    end
  end


  def full_street_address
    [venue, street_address, town, post_code, country].compact.join(', ')
  end

  def address_changed?
    attrs = %w(venue street_address town country)
    attrs.any?{|a| send "#{a}_changed?"}
  end

end
```

and

```
app/uploaders/images_uploader.rb

class ImagesUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Here's the HTTP request sent by my form.

```
"images"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f5a5994a8a8
@tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20151011-15000-rfthvn.jpg>,
@original_filename="87fcddc27a42693e-Backroom2.jpg",
@content_type="image/jpeg",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"event[images][]\"; filename=\"87fcddc27a42693e-Backroom2.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f5a599571e8 @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20151011-15000-1dxeg2k.jpg>,
@original_filename="10009818_837806636276971_1685343322891827736_n.jpg",
@content_type="image/jpeg",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"event[images][]\"; filename=\"10009818_837806636276971_1685343322891827736_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f5a59956e78 @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20151011-15000-1s6lvjd.jpg>,
@original_filename="10690041_759673270756975_1958518644007085576_n.jpg",
@content_type="image/jpeg",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"event[images][]\"; filename=\"10690041_759673270756975_1958518644007085576_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f5a59956e50 @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20151011-15000-1i5076x.jpg>,
@original_filename="10857738_809883175735984_4532818664928411079_n.jpg",
@content_type="image/jpeg",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"event[images][]\"; filename=\"10857738_809883175735984_4532818664928411079_n.jpg \"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]
```

Comment: Please show your Model and Uploader

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your CarrierWave directory correctly:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.root = File.expand_path '../public', __FILE__
end
```

Comment: I tried putting this in config/initializers/carrierwave.rb. Is that the right place for it? It doesn't seem to have changed anything

Answer (score 0):

in your event.rb model it should be: `mount_uploaders :images, ImagesUploader` instead of `mount_uploader`